# I'm having trouble understanding how to get JavaScript to function as a program

Tags: javascript, button

This is going to sound really, really basic, but I just need a little help understanding one of the concepts I'm struggling with in Javascript. I have been reading tutorials on loops, if/elseif/else and so on, I have a fairly decent understanding of them and how they work, but it's implementing and using them I am really confused about.

Just to be clear, I understand how to link my script.js file to my index.html. What I am having trouble understanding is how the Javascript I write, is influenced and connected to the HTML/CSS I write.

For example, if building a quiz, if I write a Submit button in HTML, how do I link my Javascript to that button, how does my Javascript know what I want to do with that button, and how does that button (submitting an answer > calculating how many correct answers I have submitted) connect to the rest of my Javascript input (listing questions, calculating how many correct answers I have, submitting them)?

Is there a particular name for the topic that covers this and will help me learn to understand it?

Comment: *"how do I link my Javascript to that button"* - What you're describing is called "adding a click handler" or "click event listener".  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener  You might alternatively handle the "submit" event on a `<form>` element.  It's really up to you how you want to structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about javascript events,
There is a sample example of how it works for connect HTML button by javascript

[Javascript events example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#examples)